# Asynchronous task in asp .net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

I am trying to use async, await and task to implement one of an asynchronous requirement in my web application. I have below code in my controller class. What I want is that after the flow reaches to printing "controller 1", the system starts the business method on a separate thread and without waiting for the response system should reach to print statement in controller and print "controller 2". But when I am executing the below code I am getting output pattern as this-

```
controller 1
PlandesignBS
controller 2
```

Whereas I am expecting this-

```
controller 1
controller 2 (Flow should reach here immediately rather than waiting 
               for business methods to get executed First)
```

Contoller Class Code-

```
public class PlanDetailsController : Controller
{      
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Generate(PlanDetailsVM planDetailsVM) 
    {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("controller 1");
       //calls business method to generate                       
       quoteId = await Task.Run(() => _planDesignBS.GenerateBS(planDetailsVM));
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("controller 2");

        return Json(quoteId , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Business Method Code-

```
public int GenerateBS(PandetailsDTO plandetails)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PlandesignBS");

 //STEP 1-> call to dataLogic Layer to use Entity Framework

 // STEP 2-> call to a method (this method is part of dll used 
 //in our project and we don't have any control on it)

 return quoteId
}
```

EDIT: The reason I am trying to do this is that I want to use few http Posts requests from my client side. Suppose I call the Generate action method first from my client side and then don't want to wait for the response of it and at the same time want to invoke another http post.

EDIT: Including EF code where I am getting execption when I am trying to follow few solutions.This method will be called from my GenerateBS method. I am getting exception on this line inside getSICCode method-

```
 DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("spGET_SICCode @industryClasifID,@industrySubClasifID,@SICCode OUTPUT", industryClasifID, industrySubClasifID, SICCode);
```

EF Code-

```
 public class PlanDesignRepository : Repository<myobject>, IPlanDesignRepository
{
    private IDbSet<myobject> _dbSet;
    private DbContext _dbContext;

    private IDbSet<myobject> DbSet
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dbSet == null)
            {
                _dbSet = base.UnitOfWork.Context.Set<myobject>();
            }
            return _dbSet;
        }
    }

    private DbContext DbContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dbContext == null)
            {
                _dbContext = base.UnitOfWork.Context;
            }
            return _dbContext;
        }
    }
 public string GetSICCode(IndustryClassficDO industryClassficDO)
    {

        SqlParameter industryClasifID = new SqlParameter("industryClasifID", SqlDbType.Int);
        industryClasifID.Value = industryClassficDO.IndustryClassificationId;

        SqlParameter industrySubClasifID = new SqlParameter("industrySubClasifID", SqlDbType.Int);
        industrySubClasifID.Value = industryClassficDO.IndustrySubClassificationId;

        SqlParameter SICCode = new SqlParameter("SICCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
        SICCode.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("spGET_SICCode @industryClasifID,@industrySubClasifID,@SICCode OUTPUT", industryClasifID, industrySubClasifID, SICCode);            


        return (string)(SICCode.Value);
    }
  }
```

EDIT: I have few http Post calls as shown below-

```
  AngularJS code for AJAX calls:

 $http({
 url: key_Url_Generate,
 method: Post,
 params: $scope.PlanDetails
        }).then(function (result) {
                 //Notify user for success or failure
                                  }
```

Comment: How do you Dispose your DataContext?

Comment: What should I do to Dispose it?

Comment: You should call the Dispose method but I am not telling you to Dispose it I am asking where you Dispose it because the exception you report says that the Dispose method was called but some code tried to use the object after that.

Comment: I am not familiar with angular but this looks like a single request. If you do two separate $http(...) calls they should be sent simultaneously. Make sure you do not add the second call in the callback (then function)

Comment: yeah, but I don't know why is it not working for me. I will try whatever solves my issue whether the code change in client side code or the server side code.

Comment: The server side change will not solve the issue. Where is the code for your second AJAX request?

Comment: It's similar to this one...only difference is with the url which will be pointing to different action method in the controller.

Comment: How did you determine the second request is waiting for the first one? Do the browser tools show the second request not being issued before the first completes? Do you have anything that blocks the code like an alert?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usage of await means that you are waiting for the task to complete before continuing the code. If you want it to execute simultaneously with the other code you should change it like this

```
public class PlanDetailsController : Controller
{      
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Generate(PlanDetailsVM planDetailsVM) 
    {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("controller 1");
       //calls business method to generate                       
       var task = Task.Run(() => _planDesignBS.GenerateBS(planDetailsVM));
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("controller 2");

        var quoteId = await task;
        return Json(quoteId , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

However I wouldn't recommend this as it serves no purpose and can degrade performance via starving the ASP.NET thread pool of threads. Why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: When I am trying to implement your solution, as I am using Entity Framework in my code.. I am getting DBcontext error-"The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."

Comment: I don't know where you create or Dispose your context so I cannot help with that unless you provide this code. However I still need to ask what is your end goal. What are you hoping to achieve by doing this?

Comment: The reason I am trying to do this is that I want to use few http Posts requests from my client side.  I want to call the Generate action method first from my client side and then don't want to wait for the response of it and at the same time want to invoke another http post. I will try to include the EF code as well in my question.

Comment: So you need to fire 2 AJAX requests with your client side JavaScript. Why do you need async code on the server?

Comment: Because my first AJAX request is not allowing my other AJAX request to send response unless it completes execution.

Comment: so, I am trying to fire the first AJAX request and forget about it. so that I can fire another AJAX request.

Comment: AJAX requests are independent on the client side unless you make them dependent by executing the second in the callback for the first. You can start 2 of them at the same time and they will execute simultaneously. The server code is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Well, maybe we should take a look at that code rather than trying to do something that cannot possibly solve the problem on the server. BTW there is one case where you can't do another request before the previous finishes and this is if you send too many simultaneous requests. I believe browsers set the limit on 10 or something.

Comment: for now I am trying with only two requests. I have included the AJAX related code in my question.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
quoteId = await Task.Run(() => _planDesignBS.GenerateBS(planDetailsVM));
```

**a**synchronously **waits** for the call inside `Task.Run` to complete. That's why you're seeing `"PlandesignBS"` printed and only after that you see the call to controller 2.

If you want to issue a "fire and forget" style of execution, you actually *don't want* to wait at all.

You should definitely not use `Task.Run` inside ASP.NET at all, [as it's dangerous](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx). Instead, if you're on .NET 4.5.2 and above, you can use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` or if not, you can use [`BackgroundTaskManager`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks) by Stephan Cleary, which safely registers the background thread with the application pool, so your thread doesn't get terminated once a re-cycle is invoked:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Generate(PlanDetailsVM planDetailsVM) 
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("controller 1");

   HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => _planDesignBS.GenerateBS(planDetailsVM));

   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("controller 2");
   return Json(quoteId , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

As a side note - If you're calling Entity Framework, there's usually no need to involve extra threads. Version 6 and above exposes TAP async based API's which are `Task` returning which you can use at your disposal for doing these kind of IO based queries.

Comment: I certainly am interested in using fire and forget style of execution but the problem I can't use HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem as I am using low version of .NET and can't use any 3rd party solution. Is there any other way of doing this which is applicable  for my case?

Comment: Yes, you can manually create your own implementation by implementing `IRegisteredObject` interface. [Here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) is a simple walk through which can get you started. Also, you can look at the implementation of [`BackgroundTaskManager`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks/blob/master/src/AspNetBackgroundTasks/BackgroundTaskManager.cs)

Comment: I tried to use BackgroundTaskManager but got an EF related exception. I have included the details in Question. Please see if you can help on it.

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: Exception is "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed"

Comment: thx to whoever broke msdn blogs https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you simply cannot dispatch asynchronous code that fall out of the asp.net request pipeline per se.

The async feature in asp.net MVC only improves the internal handling of threads inside the IIS process. It does NOT enable you to finish and close the response to the client, before all execution is completed.

If you want to do a real "fire-and-forget" solution, you need more than that.

I recently had the requirement that mails be sent asynchronously after a form in a web application has been submit.

The only way I found to solve this problem was to use `hangfire`:

http://hangfire.io/

Comment: He doesn't even want to fire and forget solution. After all he uses the result of the async computation in the action result. What he does is simply useless.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public class PlanDetailsController : Controller
    {      
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Generate(PlanDetailsVM planDetailsVM) 
        {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("controller 1");
           //calls business method to generate                       
           var quoteIdTask =  GenerateAsyncBs();

           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("controller 2");

int id = await quoteIdTask;

            return Json(quoteId , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    private async Task<int> GenerateBsAsync()
    {
      //do your planDetails logic here.
    }
```